# how to enable /disable form field based on selection using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am create the form with for online course. if the existing student refer the student means they will get the money.

My form contain Name,Mobile No,Email Id
Give your referral details as drop down.
Eg: i select 2 in the drop-down means it show the 2 rows form data again

Referral form value contain Name,Mobile No,City,Course Name.

Based on the selection i need to show and hide multiple form fields and
I need put validation and Mobile,City and Course is mandatory field.

Then,I need to capture the refers name and assign the students are created by referrer.

When i select refer as 2 it shows the field value two times how to do it. How to put validation

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('select#select_btn').change(function(){
 
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
 if(sel_value==0)
 {
  //Resetting Form 
  //$("#form_submit").empty();
  //$("#form1").css({'display':'none'});
 }
 else{
  //Resetting Form 
  //$("#form_submit").empty();
  
  //Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically 
     create(sel_value);
  
  //appending submit button to form
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<input/>",{type:'submit', value:'Sumbit'})
  )
  } 
 }); 
 
function create(sel_value){
   for(var i=1;i<=sel_value;i++)   
    {
    $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
    
     $("div#form1").append(
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
  $("<h3/>").text("Refer Form"+i)),
    $("<h7/>").text("Name: "),
  $("<input/>",  {type:'text', placeholder:'Name', name:'name_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
     $("<br/>"),
     $("<h7/>").text("Mobile No: "),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Mobile', name:'mobile'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
     $("<br/>"),
         $("<h7/>").text("Email: "),
  $("<input/>", {type:'email', placeholder:'Email', name:'email_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
     $("<br/>"),
     $("<h7/>").text("City: "),
    $("<select>").append('<option val="0">--Select--</option>','<option val="1">One</option>','<option val="2">Two</option>','<option val="3">Three</option>','<option val="4">Four</option>','<option val="5">Five</option>'),
 $("<br/>"),
   $("<br/>"),
   $("<h7/>").text("Course: "),
    $("<select>").append('<option val="0">--Select--</option>','<option val="1">One</option>','<option val="2">Two</option>','<option val="3">Three</option>','<option val="4">Four</option>','<option val="5">Five</option>'),
  $("<hr/>"),
  $("<br/>")
                  ))
     }
 
 }
  
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container">
<div id="form1">
<form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
   <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="player_email" />
    </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </p>

     <p> Refer:

<div id="selected_form_code">
 <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">--Select--</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
 </div>

  
  
   <!-- dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates here-->
  </form>
 </div> 
<!------ right side advertisement div ----------------->

 
</div>
<?Php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

```
when i select the refer as 2 and then it shows refer form fields 2 times.... i change refer field from 2 to 1 it shows one times of refer field.But,Now its show 3 times(2+1). How to do it....Where i did wrong????
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Hi kiran,I created the form but i dont know how to valid and how to store the refer name

Comment: I suggest you search about databases to store the refer name. You should search how to save to database with php. There are plenty of examples of these topics including validation and sanitization

Comment: ok thanks,but how to show the form field again when i click refer is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("#select_btn").val('0');
    $('#select_btn').change(function(e) {
        var selno = $(this).val();
  $('#input').empty();
  for(i=0; i < selno; i++ ){
  $('#input').append('<div class="input'+i+'"><h2>'+(i+1)+'</h2><p> Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> </p> <p> Mobile:<input type="text" name="mob" /></p><p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></p><p>City: <select id="city" name="City"><option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option><option value="Chennai">Chennai</option><option value="Delhi">Delhi</option><option value="Jammu">Jammu</option><option value="Ooty">Ooty</option></select></p><p>Course: <select id="course" name="Course"><option value="B.com">B.com</option><option value="B.A">B.A</option><option value="MBA">MBA</option><option value="B.Sc">B.Sc</option><option value="BCA">BCA</option></select></p></div>');
  }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Toggle fields based on form values</h1>
<p>Change the age field and see what happens</p>
<div id="form1">
  <form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
    <p>Name:
      <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>Email:
      <input type="text" name="player_email" />
    </p>
    <p>Mobile:
      <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </p>
    <p>Refer:
      <select id="select_btn" name="refer" value="0">
        <option value="0">select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <div id="input">
      
    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Join!" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#select_btn').change(function(e) {
        var selno = $(this).val();
  $('.input').remove();
  for(i=0; i < selno; i++ ){
  $('#input').append('<div class="input'+i+'"><p> Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> </p> <p> Mobile:<input type="text" name="mob" /></p><p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></p><p>City: <select id="city" name="City"><option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option><option value="Chennai">Chennai</option><option value="Delhi">Delhi</option><option value="Jammu">Jammu</option><option value="Ooty">Ooty</option></select></p><p>Course: <select id="course" name="Course"><option value="B.com">B.com</option><option value="B.A">B.A</option><option value="MBA">MBA</option><option value="B.Sc">B.Sc</option><option value="BCA">BCA</option></select></p></div>');
  }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Toggle fields based on form values</h1>
<p>Change the age field and see what happens</p>
<div id="form1">
  <form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
    <p>Name:
      <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>Email:
      <input type="text" name="player_email" />
    </p>
    <p>Mobile:
      <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </p>
    <p>Refer:
      <select id="select_btn" name="refer">
        <option >select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <div id="input">
      <div class="input">
        <p> Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" />
        </p>
        <p> Mobile:
          <input type="text" name="mob" />
        </p>
        <p>Email:
          <input type="text" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p>City:
          <select id="city" name="City">
            <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
            <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
            <option value="Jammu">Jammu</option>
            <option value="Ooty">Ooty</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>Course:
          <select id="course" name="Course">
            <option value="B.com">B.com</option>
            <option value="B.A">B.A</option>
            <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
            <option value="B.Sc">B.Sc</option>
            <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Join!" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, how can i set the mobile no and name is required. for example if select two in refer means it shows two form field and both fields are required. how to do it and it will increase. i need select 5 means it show the field 5 times and again select 4 means show the field  4 times only

Comment: i think are you asking form validation mobile, name, Email

Comment: when i select 2 it shows two form field again i select 3 means it (2+3) 5 form field. Total dropdown value is 5 it shows only 5 not increment the value????